# Setting hotkeys for Mu editor's Python 3 mode on a laptop + issues with the aforementioned mode's file editor

Tags: hotkeys, windows-10-desktop, python-3.12, mu

I'm using HP 250 G6 notebook PC and running Windows 10. F1, F5 don't work and I wonder if there's some way to customize hotkeys?

Also, I can't seem to get any math operations working in a file editor, but they do work fine on Python 3 REPL.

[screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw9Cl.jpg)